# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication + Docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, maven, jar

Пыталась запустить приложение на докер, но не могу побороть ошибку

```
C:\Users\Мася\Desktop\my-personal-diary>docker run -p 8082:8082 b52146e8d013
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at com.nastenkapusechka.mypersonaldiary.MyPersonalDiaryApplication.main(MyPersonalDiaryApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nastenkapusechka</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-personal-diary</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>my-personal-diary</name>
    <description>Your own!</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>com.nastenkapusechka.mypersonaldiary.MyPersonalDiaryApplication</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>3.0.2</version>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <archive>-->
<!--                        <manifest>-->
<!--                            <mainClass>com.nastenkapusechka.mypersonaldiary.MyPersonalDiaryApplication</mainClass>-->
<!--                        </manifest>-->
<!--                    </archive>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.nastenkapusechka.mypersonaldiary.MyPersonalDiaryApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

То, что под комментами - это мои попытки исправить ситуэйшн
Помогити пж!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикрепите скриншот из IDE, где видно структуру проекта, чтобы быть уверенным, что вы правильно путь указали к классу

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий, добавила

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в **pom.xml** поменяйте ваше огромное содержимое тега **build**, на

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

А **dockerfile** поменяй на это:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN mvn package
EXPOSE 8082
CMD ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]
```

Зайдите в папку вашего проекта, где лежит **dockerfile** и выполните команду `docker build -t "my_app:v1" .`
И потом `docker run -it  my_app:v1`

Comment: `FROM maven:3-jdk-11`